# Hot questions versus classic old questions

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

From reading [basic guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and related help center topic I can conclude that mostly quick_question->quick_answer is welcomed. Where "quick" is between several hours and several days.

While digging some problem I love to comment, answer and update quite old questions. Does it make sense? At the moment I suspect that my efforts to improve contents here are not much welcomed.

I *always* do a research before asking. So my questions always contain some possible answers and/or workarounds of various quality[ugliness] levels. Would asking here for perfect|clean problem solution is against the rules? Some of my questions were tagged, some were closed, some were deleted.

Comment: We would really really ***love*** to have more "slow", high quality, long-term maintained questions and answers! It's the sad reality that quick shot one-offs are the norm.

Comment: `I can conclude that mostly quick_question->quick_answer is welcomed.` That might be a misunderstanding of the guidance you linked to. Questions get put on hold and closed because five users with voting rights think there is a *problem* with them, not because they are old. "Quick question quick answer" is what mostly *happens*, but it doesn't mean that answering/editing older content isn't welcome.

Comment: Say there is an old(years) question that was not properly answered or that old answer no longer apply, but problem still stands. What is better - asking that question again in modern terms (causing dupe flags) or comment old post?

Comment: If you find an old question that you think could have a better and more up to date answer, just answer it. When people find that Q&A you'll receive upvotes for your efforts, if the community find your new answer useful. No need to create a new question if the problem is correctly described by the original one. If the change is a small one, you can provide a comment for the answerer to update their question (but there are no guarantees that the user will be around to edit their answer)

Comment: You should not be asking a new question *just* because answers were written years ago. First of all, the answers may very well still hold true. In `html` we get questions about disabled fields not submitting with the form. That's the way HTML worked in version 4 back in 1999, and the way it continues to work in version 5 in 2017. Also, asking for perfect/clean solution for any question is against the rules, because that is an opinion. One person might think that doing `~(returnsNegativeOne) ? do() : doNot();` (in JavaScript) is the pinnacle of cleanliness, but I find it distractingly obtuse.

Comment: `asking for perfect/clean solution for any question is against the rules, because that is an opinion.` - so it makes no sense for me to ask for help here as I always strive for best possible solution, correct? [For](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42503671/2746150) [instance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42170773/2746150)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying... [Meta is different](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) if you're talking about this question. The links you've shown are to answers. Multiple answers, demonstrating different methods for solving a problem, are very welcome and encouraged (although explaining how your answers are different/better would not be amiss). **Asking** for the *best* solution will get you in trouble, unless you are very specific and objective as to what "best" means to you.

Comment: @AntonKruglov yes, asking for generic "the best of all" is not welcome. Asking for better solution given very particular criteria (like "I have O(n^2) solution below but looking for O(n log n)" or "looking for refactoring to avoid `goto` from innermost loop") is definitely welcome (assuming question demonstrates research you've done already).

Comment: You get the Necromancer badge for answering old questions with better answers.

Comment: Bear in mind that a very large number of competent programmers don't need to ask new questions on SO: they find what they need by searching the archives. Most new questions these days are asked by people who don't know enough about the language or programming in general  to be able to search effectively; that can also be due to poor English skills. So don't think you're wasting your time by responding to old questions that need updated / improved answers. True, it's harder to get upvotes that way, but if you write great, useful answers the upvotes _will_ come.

Comment: By all means, please rescue my unanswered questions ;)